# AngularJS UI Router linking to a State with URL Parameters inbetween the state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I've got some state routing like:

```
.state. ('home', { ... })

.state('home.company', {
    url: 'company/{ID:int}',
    abstract: true,
    template: '<ui-view/>'
})

.state('home.company.list', {
    url: '/list',
    views: { ... }
```

I want to use something like this:

```
ui-sref="home.company({ ID: id }).list"
```

to navigate to the state. But it doesn't work. I also tried to do following:

```
ui-sref="home.company.list({ ID: id })"
```

This also doesn't work. Any tips how to get it working?

P.S. It would work if I have used:

```
$state.go(route, { ID: id });
```

Where `state` would be `'home.company.list'`. But it isn't what I currently want to achieve.

P.P.S
Here is the error I get:

> Error: Invalid state ref 'home.company({ ID: id }).list>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HzGlj3yRhZlf0LoYu0L4?p=preview)

The above states seems to be ok. I just adjusted them a bit and it is working.

- added url def for home state
- converted `<ui-view />` to more common and supported `<div ui-view=""></div>`

Here is the snippet

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
      template: '<div ui-view=""></div>',
      url: "/home"

  })
  .state('home.company', {
      url: 'company/{ID:int}',
      abstract: true,
      template: '<div ui-view=""></div>',
  })

  .state('home.company.list', {
      url: '/list',
      views: {
        '': {
          templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
        }
      }
  })
```

These are links which do what is expected

```
<a ui-sref="home.company.list({ ID: 1 })">
<a ui-sref="home.company.list({ ID: 22 })">
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HzGlj3yRhZlf0LoYu0L4?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your responce, but your solution unfortunately doesn't work for me. I tried the link in Comodo Dragon, IE and the newest Mozilla.

Comment: Ok, I should "fix" all the issue and make them standard... as I did that now. Check my extended answer, and updated plunker. It should now work for you in any browser (tested IE, Chrome...)

Comment: Now it works correctly. Thanks. I mark your post as the answer asap.

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow ;) Enjoy mighty UI-Router, sir!